# Findings rows in RREF matrix which contain nothing but a pivot

Tags: matrix

I am asked to find all rows in a matrix in reduced row echelon form which contain nothing but pivots (pivot is $1$, all other entries are $0$).

For example, in this matrix:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\sim
\begin{bmatrix}
\color{red}1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \color{red}1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
the rows whose pivots are marked in red are such rows.

I wrote the following code:

```
matrix = {{1, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1}}; (* Same example. *)
reduced = RowReduce[matrix]
For[i = 1, i <= Length[reduced], ++i,
  row = reduced[[i]];
  onlyPivot = False;
  Clear[pivot];
  For[j = 1, j <= Length[row], ++j,
   If[And[row[[j]] != 0, Not[ValueQ[pivot]]],
     pivot = row[[j]];
     onlyPivot = True,
     If[And[row[[j]] != 0, ValueQ[pivot]],
      onlyPivot = False
      ]
     ];
   ];
  Print[onlyPivot];
  ];
```

As you can notice, this is very... C-like (at least it works), and probably very inefficient. Is there a better way to do this in Mathematica? What should I be looking into?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Mathematica.SE, please consider taking the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) so you learn the basics of the site. Once you gain enough reputation by making [good questions](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) you will be able to vote up and down both questions and answers. When you see good ones, please vote them up by clicking the grey triangles, because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. As you receive help, try to give it too, by *answering questions* in your area of expertise.

Comment: Can be done with a `Cases` pattern match. If the reduced matrix is `rref` then could do `In[24]:= Cases[rref, {0 ..., 1, 0 ...}]

Out[24]= {{1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
matrix = {{1, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1}};(*Same example.*)
(reduced = RowReduce[matrix]) // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
r = MapIndexed[{First[#2], Count[#1, 1]} &, reduced];
r = Insert[r, {"row number", "number of 1 in row"}, 1];
Grid[r, Frame -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Or to make nice report, you can add tag field:

```
r = MapIndexed[{First[#2], z = Count[#1, 1]; z, If[z == 1, "Yes!", "No"]} &, reduced];
r = Insert[r, {"row number", "number of 1 in row", " result"}, 1];
Grid[r, Frame -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks a lot! `MapIndexed` is a great thing!

Answer (score 1):

```
pcF = Length /@ SparseArray[#]["AdjacencyLists"] &;

pcF@reduced
(* {1, 2, 1} *)

Row[Grid /@ {matrix, reduced, List /@ (pcF@reduced)}, Spacer[10]]
```

[image]

```
pcF2 = Length[#] == 1 & /@ SparseArray[#]["AdjacencyLists"] &;
pcF2@reduced
(* {True, False, True} *)
Row[Grid /@ {matrix, reduced, List /@ (pcF2@reduced)}, Spacer[10]]
```

[image]